# How tensorflow.nn.ctc_loss works in tensorflow 2 and how to use it for handwritting recognition?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I try to create a simple model for handwritting recognition with tensorflow 2.8 based on [this keras example](https://keras.io/examples/vision/handwriting_recognition/#resizing-images-without-distortion) but I have trouble understanding how the CTC loss [tensorflow.nn.ctc_loss](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/ctc_loss) works and how to use it in my code.

I use images representing words from the [IAM dataset](https://fki.tic.heia-fr.ch/databases/iam-handwriting-database) :

- Images are resized to shape (256, 64, 1)
- Words are tokenized to sequences of shape 21 (max word length)

```py
IMG_WIDTH = 256
IMG_HEIGHT = 64

def preprocess_image(image_path, width=IMG_WIDTH, height=IMG_HEIGHT):
    image = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
    image = tf.image.decode_png(image)
    image = tf.image.resize_with_pad(image, height, width, method="lanczos3")
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255.0
    image = tf.transpose(image, perm=[1, 0, 2])
    image = tf.image.flip_left_right(image)

    return image

tokenizer = tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer(
    filters="",
    lower=False,
    split="",
    char_level=True,
    oov_token="_"
)

tokenizer.fit_on_texts(transcriptions)
print(" ".join(sorted(tokenizer.word_counts.keys())))
#  ! " # & ' ( ) * + , - . / 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : ; ? A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z

MAX_LEN_WORD = max(len(wm.transcription) for wm in words_meta)

def pad_sequences(sequences):
    return tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(
        sequences, 
        maxlen=MAX_LEN_WORD, 
        padding="pre", 
        truncating="pre", 
        # value=tokenizer.word_index[pad_value]
    )

print(pad_sequences(tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(["hello"])))
# array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 4, 12, 13, 3]])
```

I tried to reuse the CTCLayer from the [keras example](https://keras.io/examples/vision/handwriting_recognition/#resizing-images-without-distortion) :

```py
class CTCLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, name=None):
        super(CTCLayer, self).__init__(name=name)

    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        batch_len = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_true)[0], dtype="int64")
        input_length = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_pred)[1], dtype="int64")
        label_length = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_true)[1], dtype="int64")

        input_length = input_length * tf.ones(shape=(batch_len, 1), dtype="int64")
        label_length = label_length * tf.ones(shape=(batch_len, 1), dtype="int64")
        loss = tf.nn.ctc_loss(y_true, y_pred, input_length, label_length)
        self.add_loss(loss)

        # At test time, just return the computed predictions.
        return y_pred
```

But when I try to construct a model with it I get an error :

```py
input_img = tf.keras.Input(shape=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, 1), name="images")
labels = tf.keras.Input(shape=(MAX_LEN_WORD,), name="labels", dtype=tf.int32)

x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation="relu", padding="same")(input_img)
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)

shape = x.get_shape()

x = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((shape[1], shape[2] * shape[3]))(x)

x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")(x)

x = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=True)
)(x)

x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(
    len(tokenizer.word_counts) + 2, activation="softmax"
)(x)


output = CTCLayer(name="ctc_loss")(labels, x)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(
    inputs=[input_img, labels], outputs=output, name="handwriting_recognizer"
)


model.compile(optimizer="adam")
model.summary()
```

The error :

```
ValueError
Traceback (most recent call last) handwriting_reco.ipynb Cell 31' in <cell line: 22>()
     13 x = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(
     14     tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=True)
     15 )(x)
     17 x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(
     18     len(tokenizer.word_counts) + 2, activation="softmax"
     19 )(x)
---> 22 output = CTCLayer(name="ctc_loss")(labels, x)
     24 model = tf.keras.models.Model(
     25     inputs=[input_img, labels], outputs=output, name="handwriting_recognizer"
     26 )
     29 model.compile(optimizer="adam")

File C:\Apps\anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:67, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65 except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66   filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67   raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68 finally:
     69   del filtered_tb

File C:\Apps\anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py:692, in convert.<locals>.decorator.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    690 except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    691   if hasattr(e, 'ag_error_metadata'):
--> 692     raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    693   else:
    694     raise

ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "ctc_loss" (type CTCLayer).

in user code:

    File "ipykernel_25428\280978635.py", line 14, in call  *
        loss = self.loss_fn(y_true, y_pred, input_length, label_length)

    ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 2 and 22 for '{{node ctc_loss/ctc_loss_dense/mul_1}} = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT](ctc_loss/ctc_loss_dense/ones, ctc_loss/ctc_loss_dense/one_hot_2)' with input shapes: [2,1,?], [22,?,1].


Call arguments received:
  • y_true=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 21), dtype=int32)
  • y_pred=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 128, 81), dtype=float32)
```

I also tried to use the `tf.nn.ctc_loss` function with simple tensors but I do not get how it works.

How could I use the CTC loss for my model in this use case ?

EDIT :

If I remove the `CTCLayer` this is what I obtain with `model.summary()` :

```
Model: "handwriting_recognizer"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 images (InputLayer)            [(None, 256, 64, 1)  0           []                               
                                ]                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_1 (Conv2D)              (None, 256, 64, 64)  640         ['images[0][0]']                 
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 128, 32, 64)  0          ['conv2d_1[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
 reshape_1 (Reshape)            (None, 128, 2048)    0           ['max_pooling2d_1[0][0]']        
                                                                                                  
 dense_2 (Dense)                (None, 128, 64)      131136      ['reshape_1[0][0]']              
                                                                                                  
 bidirectional_1 (Bidirectional  (None, 128, 256)    197632      ['dense_2[0][0]']                
 )                                                                                                
                                                                                                  
 labels (InputLayer)            [(None, 21)]         0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 dense_3 (Dense)                (None, 128, 81)      20817       ['bidirectional_1[0][0]']        
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 350,225
Trainable params: 350,225
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Could you display the model summary ?

Comment: I have an error before `model.summary()` but I added the summary for a model without the `CTCLayer` in my question